# Copy files from SharePoint to Azure Blob without downloading

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, microsoft-graph

Is it possible to use copy files from SharePoint Online to Azure Blob without downloading them to the local computer first using C#?

I have been looking at Azure.Storage, and it appears the upload methods take in a stream, or bytes. But this would mean the machine running the application would first download the stream and then upload it.

Comment: Traditional methods involve downloading the files locally before uploading them, which can be inefficient. However, we have a solution that can streamline this process for you. Our SharePoint to Azure Blob Storage migration tool is designed to handle these types of scenarios. This means you can save time and bandwidth while achieving a more efficient and seamless migration. If you're interested in learning more about how our migration tool works and how it can benefit your specific use case, I recommend [booking a demo with us](https://katprotech.com/sharepoint-to-azure-blob-migration/). Our t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5893/transfer-files-from-sharepoint-to-blob-storage-with-azure-logic-apps/) and [this](https://medium.com/@amarpreet_singh/moving-files-from-sharepoint-to-azure-blob-d5e71d32259f) articles, you can create Azure logic app that does the transfer for you. Although articles are one and two years old, idea is valid - use Azure Logic app, Azure Function, Power Automate or Power App.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes this works but I was hoping to create a Client in c#.

I realised that its not possible, you must first upload the file to Azure, and then you can copy from Azure to SharePoint via the SharePoint Migration API.

Comment: Yep, that is true. Glad it helped!